# How does the Operating System determine how much stack space should be allotted to each thread?

Tags: multithreading, memory, memory-management, concurrency, operating-system

How does the OS determine how much stack space will be given to each thread in the address space of underlying process?

And what if a thread utilizes all stack space allotted to it initially and there exists a lot of underutilized space by the other threads of the same process?
I understand that a problem of the same sort b/w a stack and a heap is resolved by both of them growing in the opposite directions.

Does the OS allot more space somewhere else in the memory to the thread, or does it cause a stack overflow?

Comment: What happens when a thread exhausts its stack? The answer is up top above your question.

Comment: But what if there was a lot of underutilized space by the other threads in the process' address space, does it still cause a stack overflow?

Comment: Yes. Each thread's stack is separate and independent of other thread stacks. Mingling them would in general be a very bad idea.

Comment: On Windows, [the default stack space is 1MB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), for reference.  So that's part of the `CreateThread` API.

Comment: It's a difficult question to answer in the case of virtual memory.  Thread stacks are, in general, swappable.  It depends on what you mean by 'alloted to it'.

Comment: Normally you have virtual memory and physical memory. A piece of virtual memory is allocated for the stack when you create a thread. Physical memory is assigned to that virtual memory on demand. And once physical memory is assigned, it could be swapped out. And some systems can, if there's room in the virtual address space, automatically grow the stack if needed.

Comment: By 'allotted to it' I mean the distance b/w the stack pointers (of empty stacks) of the two adjacent stacks in the address space of the process, the threads are a part of.
Just like the white space shown in this picture for each thread's stack.
http://www.roguewave.com/portals/0/products/legacy-hpp/docs/thrug/images/stackallocation.gif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't up to the OS to decide that, it is a programmer's job.  Taking Windows as an example, the stack size of the *first* thread, the one that the OS starts, is specified in the executable file header.  The [IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.SizeOfStackReserve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) sets the size.  Which passes the buck to whatever tool generated the header, like the linker, you use its [/STACK option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8cxs58a6.aspx) to set the size.

Most build tools will use a reasonable default size, one megabyte for the reserve size is very common, 4096 (one page) for the initial commit size.  Or not so reasonable defaults, .NET programs infamously commit the entire stack space up front.

This also needs to be specified when you start a thread, a winapi function like [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) takes an argument to set the size.  A default is available, if you specify 0 then the OS uses the size specified in the EXE header.  This is very common, the actual size is rarely critical since most programs will heavily oversize the stack.  Important to stay well away from disaster.  Do note that oversizing the stack doesn't cost anything on a demand-paged operating system, you only pay for what you use.

Running out of stack space is an unrecoverable error in many cases, the processor cannot make calls anymore.  The reason for this web-site's name.  That there are other threads around that didn't consume their entire stack is irrelevant, switching stacks can in general not work.  Programs use pointers to stack space, you can't find them back to update the value.

Comment: Does this mean that if a thread has utilized the default stack space the programmer wanted it to have and beyond that space the stack space of the next thread starts, the program would give me a stack overflow, or can this stack can be swapped out from its current location in the memory and stored in some other place in the memory where space is available, after making changes to the virtual memory map?

Comment: Asked and answered.  You do need to stop assuming that "swapping" can work.  It can't.  Learning the C language is a good way to understand the machine.